# Custom ListView adapter Force close :(

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am a newbe to android and have been following the tutorials posted online to experiment with coding for android. I am trying to display a list which has input from two different arrays, but every time i run the code i keep on getting a force close and can seem to figure out what i am doing wrong. here is my code ( this is from an online tutorial)

Main.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="vertical" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:text="List of Country &amp; their denotation" 
          android:textStyle="normal|bold" 
          android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"> 
  </TextView>
  <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:gravity="left|center"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:paddingBottom="5px"
              android:paddingTop="5px" 
              android:paddingLeft="5px">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/bg" 
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:text="hi"/>

  <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView02" 
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px" 
            android:textColor="#0099CC"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

display.java

```
package com.example.display

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class customlistview extends Activity {

  private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private LayoutInflater mInflater;

  public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }

  public int getCount() {
    return country.length;
  }

  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
      holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
      holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);

      convertView.setTag(holder);
      } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }

      holder.text.setText(curr[position]);
      holder.text2.setText(country[position]);

      return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
      TextView text;
      TextView text2;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
  }

  private static final String[] country = { "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho ", "Liberia", "Libya", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg" };

  private static final String[] curr = { "ISK", "INR", "IDR", "IRR", "IQD", "EUR", "ILS", "EUR", "LAK", "LVL", "LBP", "LSL ", "LRD", "LYD", "LTL ", "EUR"};

}
```

This code can also be found at http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/,

I have tried several times, changing different values and even trying to print one array but have been unsuccessful at it and keep on getting a force close. I would appreciate it if someone would be able to point out what is wrong with the code and point me in the right direction.

Comment: can you attach your Log of error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include your activity file inside AndroidManifest.xml file.
Every Activity Needs to be included in this xml file.
Syntax:

Also check your launcher activity is set in xml file